# How do I display gerrit change id in shell prompt?

Tags: git, zsh, gerrit

Did anyone manage to get gerrit changeid in shell prompt?

I am using zsh.

Comment: Do you want to display a `Change-ID` of the currently `checked-out` commit?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer without waiting for the answer I asked in the
comments.  Notice that `zsh` is not my primary shell but I use `bash`
that is a bit similar.  To do what you want:

```
in_git() {
     git rev-parse  --git-dir >/dev/null 2>&1
}

precmd() {
     in_git && PS1="$(git show --format=%B  -s | grep Change-Id: | cut -d " " -f2) $ " || PS1="$ "
}
```

Function called `in_git` checks if you're currently inside `git`
repository - if you are we try to extract `Change-Id` from the current
commit and if you aren't we simply display `$` as the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in .zshrc file like this:

```
get-change () { git show $1 --format=%B  -s | grep Change-Id: | cut -d " " -f2; }
```

Then if you execute "get-change" without parameters you get the Change-Id of the HEAD commit:

```
get-change
I694a3cee135c711e2df231cb84ab6c58183a4846
```

Or, if you prefer, you can get the Change-Id of any other commit:

```
get-change master
I2cb7970b909322ff2c78a2326cf42dd2f6ae9975

get-change v1.0.0
Ia037c862c038ba78aba3724d12ba99ce298cbc55

get-change 7d09af3
I974b884a1699a798d569f0f638aa90bf531f76fe
```

Comment: IMO OP wants to have `Change-Id` in the `PS1` - that is what he means by a *prompt*`, he also used [tag:PS1] tag.